# Using `hook_field_attach_presave` for replacing characters

Tags: 8, hooks

In Drupal 7, I used hook_field_attach_presave() to replace characters of a body field in the moment when the node is saved. Now i want to use the code for Drupal 8, but could not get it to work:

```
function my_module_field_attach_presave($entity_type, $entity){
  dpm($entity);
  $replacement_pattern = '/(?<=\d\ )x(?= \d)/'; // replace a "x" surrounded by numbers with symbol "×"
  if(!empty($entity->body->value)){
    $entity->body->value = preg_replace($replacement_pattern, ' &times; ', $entity->body->value);
```

}
The above code does not work, not even the dpm($entity) is printed. What is the problem here, is the hook not available in D8? I just found it [here](http://api.hostdog.eu/api/drupal-8/functions?object_name=&summary=&order=title&sort=desc&page=43), not on official drupal sites. So if it does not exist, what's the alternative?

EDIT: Thanks to @Clive I got it working. Here's the code:

```
function my_module_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  $entity->setTitle('dd The new Title');
  $replacement_pattern = '/(?<=\d\ )x(?= \d)/'; 
  if(!empty($entity->body->value)){
    $entity->body->value = preg_replace($replacement_pattern, ' &times; ', $entity->body->value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_field_attach_presave()` was [removed some time ago](https://www.drupal.org/node/2078765), there's no such operation in Drupal 8.

You can, however, use [`hook_entity_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x) or  [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x) instead.